# do not assign default values when creating model from dict in pydantic

Tags: python, pydantic

I have a pydantic model with optional fields that have default values. I use this model to generate  a JSON schema for another tool, so it can know the default values to apply if it chooses to assign a field.

```
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    my_field: Optional[str] = None
    my_other_field: Optional[str] = "aaaaaaaaaaab"

my_dict = {"my_field": "value"}
my_model = MyModel(**my_dict)

# prints: {"my_field": "value", "my_other_field": "aaaaaaaaaaab"}
print(my_model)
```

So in this case, I want `my_model` to have just my_field assigned, and not `my_other_field` to not be assigned. `my_other_field` may or may not be in the dictionary, so if it's not present, I don't want it to be in the resulting model object.

I can not find a way to customize construction of the model from a dict and have it ignore assigning a default.

So essentially, I want the defaults to be present when I call MyModel.schema(), but not when I construct the model from a dict. Is this possible?

Note that my model is hierarchical and has nested models, but isn't shown above.

Comment: I think it's a bad idea? All code that try to use `my_other_field` will have to wary about a possible `AttributeError`.

Comment: What do you mean, you don't want it to be assigned? Then what _should_ the value of that field be? The field has to have **some** value. It can be `None` or some other sentinel value, but it cannot just "not be there". Either you have a field or you don't. There is no such thing as a field without a value.

Comment: Also, you want the schema to show a default value, but that default value to **never be used**. Isn't that super confusing?

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse the type of the attribute with the type of the *argument* that can be passed to initialize it. `my_field` has type `Optional[str]` because the default value is `None`. `my_other_field` should have type `str` because the default value is, in fact, another `str` value.

`Optional[foo]` is just a synonym for `Union[foo, None]`. It doesn't mean that you can optionally provide a value to initialize the field; that's indicated by assigning a value to the name.

The possibilities are

```
class Foo(BaseModel):
    f1: str   # Must provide a string when instantiating Foo
    f2: Optional[str]  # Must provide a string or None when instantiating Foo
    f3: str = "bar"  # Can provide a string, or "bar" will be used
    f4: Optional[str] = "bar"  # Can provide a string or None, or "bar" will be used 
    f5: Optional[str] = None  # Can provide a string or none, or None will be used
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand the typing. I'm trying to figure out if I can serialize to the model object but skip populating the defaults.

Comment: @StealthRabbi You mean **de**serialize to the model. And not populating the default values **that you defined yourself** makes zero sense.